# Kendo UI grid: close icon and sort arrow missing on column-header dragged to the grouping panel

Tags: css, grid, grouping, kendo-ui

In the example of the grid shown in the Kendo UI website [web demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) area, when the column-header is dragged to the group box, the column header gets two little images: the sort arrow and the close (X).  As far as I can tell, the only relevant CSS on this demo would come from the two stylesheets and the js library referenced in the head section of the page:

```
<script src="source/kendo.all.js"></script>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have the minified versions of these files referenced in the head section of my own page (using the Kendo controls downloaded a few days ago) and on my page these two images on the dragged/dropped column header are not appearing in IE9 in IE9 Standards Mode, in Opera, Safari, or Chrome.  Only the column header text appears there as the button text.

Is it possible that the download files and the libraries referenced in these demos are not identical?

**It would be very helpful to have these demos point to an external public library so someone trying to duplicate the behavior could be certain that everything is the same.**

Comment: Have you copied all kendo images/spritesheets to the correct locations?

Comment: Where did you get the minified CSS? Image sprite file for `Default` theme is `styles/Default/sprite.png`. Do you have this file?

Comment: @Tim have you made any progress here?

Answer (score 0):

yes from the demo code and the image file is missing in the  libraries mentioned in the code ..
To make it working ..First find out the missing files using chrome Dev Tools(Press F12 and see console)..Then within the downloaded Kenodui.zip files find the Image file (here styles/Default/sprite.png) and place it with appropriate Heirarchial structure(this part is important ..you may need to create new folders for it)..